# ¿Por qué no se muestra mi variable PHP?

Tags: php, html

Estoy pasando un valor de un formulario a otra página, en esta página lo recupero por `$_POST` y de ahí quiero mostrarlo pero no se muestra. ¿Por qué ocurre y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Código formulario:

```
<form action="guardarpaciente.php" method="post" >
<div class="formularioregistro">

      <legend>DATOS PERSONALES&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
       &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;        
      DATOS CLINICOS</legend>       
            <div id="tipo_Documento">
                <select>
                   <option>Tipo de documento</option>
                    <option value="dni">DNI</option>
                    <option value="pn">PN</option>
                    <option value="ce">CE</option>
                    <option value="sd">SD</option>              
                </select>
            </div>
            <div id="txtDni">
                <input type="text" name="dni"   maxlength="8" placeholder="Numero de documento" style="height: 20%;">
            </div>
            <div id="condicioningreso">
                <select>
                   <option>Condicion de ingreso</option>
                    <option value="dni">Nuevo</option>
                    <option value="pn">Recaida</option>
                    <option value="ce">Fracaso</option>
                    <option value="sd">Abandono</option> 
                    <option value="sd">Transferencia</option> 
                    <option value="sd">otro</option> 


                </select>
            </div>

            <div id="contenedor4">      
                <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" style="height: 20%; width: 11.5%;" >          
            <div id="txtapellidop">
                <input type="text" name="apellidop" placeholder="Apellido Paterno" style="height: 20%; width: 128%;">
            </div>
            <div id="txtapellidom">
                <input type="text" name="apellidom" placeholder="Apellido Materno" style="height: 20%; width: 128%;">
            </div>
            <div id="txtnumerocaso">
                <input type="text" name="numero_de_caso" placeholder="Numero de caso" style="height: 20%;" >
            </div>
            </div>
            <div id="contenedor7">
            <div id="fchanacimiento">

             <label>Fecha de nacimiento</label><input type="date" name="fechanac" style="height: 20%;width: 128%;" >

            </div>
            <div id="historiacli">
                <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Numero de historia clinica" style="height: 20%;" >
            </div>

            </div>
            <div id="sexo">
                 <select>
                   <option>Sexo</option>
                    <option value="1">Masculino</option>
                    <option value="2">Femenino</option>

                </select>
            </div>
            <div id="contenedor5">
            <div id="talla">
                <input type="text" name="apellidom" placeholder="Talla" style="height: 20%; width: 128%;"> 
            </div>
            <div id="peso">
                <input type="text" name="apellidom" placeholder="Peso" style="height: 20%; width: 128%;">
            </div>
            </div>

            <div id="contenedor6">
            <div id="telefono">
                <input type="text" name="telefono" placeholder="telefono" style="height: 20%; width: 128%;">
            </div>
             <div id="celular">
                <input type="text" name="celular" placeholder="celular" style="height: 20%; width: 128%;">
            </div>
           </div>

           <div id="contenedor8">
               <select id="pais">
                   <option>Pais</option>
                    <option>Peru</option>


 <option>Uruguay</option>

           </select>

           <select id="departamento">
               <option>Departamento</option>
                <option>Peru</option>
               <option>Uruguay</option>

           </select>
       </div>

          <select id="provincia">
               <option>Provincia</option>
                <option>Peru</option>
               <option>Uruguay</option>

           </select>

           <select id="distrito">
               <option>Distrito</option>
                <option>Peru</option>
               <option>Uruguay</option>

           </select>

       <div id="direccion">
           <input type="text" name="direccion" placeholder="Direcion" style="height: 20%; width: 38%;">
       </div>

        <input id="btnguardar" type="submit" value="Guardar" name="Guardar" class="btn-enviar">


   </div>

</form>
```

Código de página destino:

```
<?php 

$nombre=$_POST["nombre"];

echo $nombre;

 ?>
```

Comment: Tienes dos inputs con `name='nombre'` probablemente eso esté causando conflictos con tu variable `$_POST`

Comment: Todos esos `&nbsp;` me hacen daño a los ojos

Comment: Lo que ocurre realmente en que por _$_POST_ se envía el valor del último elemento con el atributo name _(en caso se repitan)_, probablemente para que no muestre nada es que el valor de _Historia Clínica_  esté vacío.

Comment: Y también tienes repetido el campo apellidom, así que en este caso te pasaría igual a la hora de recoger los valores.

Comment: gracias,era eso no me habia dado cuenta

Comment: Creo que @Dev.Joel debería publicar una respuesta que sea marcada como solución. Por otra parte, es sorprendente ver tannntos `&nbsp;` esos espacios los puedes dar usando CSS, y si de todos modos te gustan más los `&nbsp;` puedes imprimirlos usando un bucle for . De veras, no deja de sorprenderme :) hasta quería contarlos a ver cuántos hay.